# Solidity - how do i transfer from another contract to msg.sender

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I would like to know how i set the origin from the transfer...

I have this contract (my actual contract is bigger than that, but that is the part that matters...):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Testing{
    address payable public manager;

    constructor(){
         manager =payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function getMoneyFromManager(uint quantity) public payable{
        //someone different from manager should recieve money from manager
        //something like: msg.sender.transfer(quantity) => FROM MANAGER
    }

}
```

But i don't know how to set the origin from the transfer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

so you want to transfer ETH/BNB (native blockchain's crypto) fomr manager to user through the contract, but i'm sorry, **you can't**
is impossible take native crypto from an address and transfer it to another through smart contracts

**but anyway there are 2 solutions:**

1. keep native crypto inside the contract and not inside the manager wallet, so when you call that function, the contract will transfer native crypto from it self `address(this)` to the user
2. use wrapped token instead, with tokens you can do what you are trying to do. The wallet manager must approve within the token contract your actual contract to spend his token

then the contract will be like:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

IMPORT "@openzeppelin/contracts/tokens/ERC20/IERC20.sol";


contract Testing{
    address public manager;
    IERC20 wETH;

    constructor(IERC20 _wETH){
         manager =msg.sender;
         wETH = _wETH;
    }

    function getMoneyFromManager(uint quantity) public payable{
        //msg.sender will receive money from manager
        wETH.transferFrom(manager, msg.sender, quantity)
    }

}
```

**NOTE:**

Make `getMoneyFromManager` function onlyOwner, otherwise everyone will be able to get money

Comment: Hmmm thats new info for me. How can i interact with this IERC20 Coin that i deployed in my contract? How another contract buy / sell coins? If you have some material. i know the basics of solidity and really got stuck on this transactions parts.

Comment: IERC20 isn't a coin, is only an interface that will help you to interact with other tokens

Comment: Ok, so, for my contract interactions i need to deploy a token? I'm kind lost to make my contract transactions works.... like, i'm building a simple contract to learn blockchain, and my next step is managing transactions. Actually is like this NFT games. Manager deploys a game. Players buy teams, If team won players get money.....

Do you have a simple example how to deal with transactions like these?
I was trying to trasnfer ether direclty, but i realize that is not the way....